# Dynamically string function calls by looping through an object in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

This is loosely related to [an earlier question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198945/coffeescript-dynamically-create-call-a-function-from-a-list-on-select-box-value), though with a different image editing library ([CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/docs) instead of Pixastic) and the code refactored somewhat.

I'm trying to write a function `changify` that reverts the HTML5 image canvas to its original state, and then runs a number of preset changes to it. This code, which loads the right canvas element `imageClipName` from a list called `camanCache`, works:

```
changify = (imageClipName) ->
    camanCache[imageClipName].revert ->
        camanCache[imageClipName]
            .brightness(10)
            .contrast(10)
            .noise(10)
            .render()
    console.log(camanCache[imageClipName])
```

But what I want is to find the saved preset changes from another list called `imageValues` and dynamically create the string of image function changes from the key value pairs of that list. Here's what I've tried to do, that fails:

```
imageClipName = "image_1"
imageValues = {image_1:{brightness: 10, contrast: 10, noise: 10}, image_2:{...}...}

changify = (imageClipName) ->
    camanCache[imageClipName].revert ->
        camanCache[imageClipName]
            for o in imageValues when o.id == imageClipName
                for key, val of o
                    .#{key}(val)
            .render()
```

This gives me a coffeescript syntax error for the third line of the `changify` function (`Unexpected 'INDENT'`), but I suspect that `.#{key}(val)` won't work for appending multiple functions to `camanCache[imageClipName]`. How to dynamically string function calls like this in coffeescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
changify = (imageClipName) ->
    camanCache[imageClipName].revert -> 
        clip = camanCache[imageClipName]
        for id, methods of imageValues when id == imageClipName
            for name, arg of methods
                clip = clip[name](arg)
            clip.render()
```

Note the switch to `for ... of` in the outer loop since you're iterating over an object, `for ... in` is for arrays in CoffeeScript.

So given this:

```
{brightness: 10, contrast: 10, noise: 10}
```

in `methods`, this loop:

```
clip = camanCache[imageClipName]
for name, arg of methods
    clip = clip[name](arg)
clip.render()
```

would have the same effect as:

```
camanCache[imageClipName].brightness(10).contrast(10).noise(10).render()
```

The order of the `key, val` pairs when iterating over the object `o` is not defined so there is no guarantee about the order of the `brightness`, `contrast`, and `noise` calls. If you need them in a specific order then you'd have to use an array for `methods`:

```
imageValues = {image_1: [['brightness', 10], ['contrast', 10], ['noise', 10]], ... }

changify = (imageClipName) ->
    camanCache[imageClipName].revert -> 
        clip = camanCache[imageClipName]
        for id, methods of imageValues when id == imageClipName
            for method in methods
                clip = clip[method[0]](method[1])
            clip.render()
```

or a bit nicer:

```
imageValues = {image_1: [ {name: 'brightness', arg: 10}, {name: 'contrast', arg: 10}, {name: 'noise', arg: 10}], ... }

changify = (imageClipName) ->
    camanCache[imageClipName].revert -> 
        clip = camanCache[imageClipName]
        for id, methods of imageValues when id == imageClipName
            for method in methods
                clip = clip[method.name](method.arg)
            clip.render()
```

Comment: Wow, very useful information about the undefined order of iteration. Is the order of iteration a javascript legacy, or something unique to coffeescript?

Comment: @Michael: That's straight JavaScript, there are some links to the relevant sections of the spec over [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10624559/479863). It is very rare for a key/value store to have a defined order, Ruby 1.9's Hashes are the only order key/value objects I've come across.

Comment: Thanks again. Clearly, I'm a bit spoiled on Ruby :)